# i2c-bus electrically damaged due to wrong wiring

Tags: i2c, electronics

In a hurry I mistakenly connected the VCC of the Bmp280 to ground and the ground of the Bmp280 to 5V.

Afterwards, I checked the i2c-bus with another sensor but `i2cdetect -y 1` only reported `--`.

**Q** How can I determine with simple means (no oscilloscope) what I bricked? Bmp280-sensor, i2c-bus on rPi, both, what else?

Comment: It sounds like you have destroyed the BMP280.

Comment: @joan Unfortunately, you're right I blew the BMP280 but the good news is the i2c-bus on the rPi is alive.

Comment: How is this related to I2C at all? All I see is power and ground were flipped

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Run (my) [gpiotest](https://elinux.org/R-Pi_Troubleshooting#Testing) or run wiringPi's pintest.

For both tests nothing should be connected to the expansion header.